# Getting the DataGrid Columns value c#

Tags: mysql, wpf, datagrid

I have to get a cell's value from a DataGrid, but i get exception when i try to use `TbRogDatum.Text = Convert.ToString(((DataRowView)DgUjMegrendeles.SelectedItem).Row["MEGRENDEL"]);` this code i get an "ArgumentException" exc. with "Additional information: The „MEGRENDEL” column is not included to the 'beszallitoi_megrendeles' table."
I am using mysql query to fill the DataGrid, and the query contains the `DATE_FORMAT(Vmegrendeles_datuma, \"%Y-%m-%d\") as 'MEGRENDEL'`  column. Any idea what to do? (btw i could get the cells value anytime this way but here it doesnt work)

EDIT:
Here is the DataGrid binding:

```
string q = "Select azonosito as 'AZ', DATE_FORMAT(Vmegrendeles_datuma, \"%Y-%m-%d\") as MEGRENDEL, DATE_FORMAT(KertSzDatum, \"%Y-%m-%d\") as 'KERTSZDATUM', vevo_csoport As VEVO_CSOPORT,"
                  + " rovidvevonev AS 'ROVIDVEVONEV',gyarto AS 'GYARTO',megnevezes AS 'MEGNEVEZES', darab AS 'DARAB'," +
                  "megjegyzes AS 'MEGJEGYZES' ,vrendelesiazonosito as 'RENDSZAM',brendelesiazonosito As BRENDSZAM,rogzito_neve AS ROGNEV,beszallito AS BESZALLITO," +
                  "DATE_FORMAT(megrendeles_datuma, \"%Y-%m-%d\") AS MEGREND,DATE_FORMAT(varhato_erkezes, \"%Y-%m-%d\") AS VARERK,csomagkuldo_ceg AS CSKULD,megjegyzes2 AS MEGJEGY2," +
                  "megrendelt AS BMEGREND,DATE_FORMAT(beerkezes_datuma, \"%Y-%m-%d\") As 'BERKDAT', beerkezett as 'BEERK' from `beszallitoi_megrendeles` "
                  + " where megrendelt='1' and beerkezett='0' order by megrendeles_datuma desc;";
        parancs = new MySqlCommand(q, Kapcsolat);
        Kapcsolat.Open();
        parancs.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Kapcsolat.Close();
        MySqlDataAdapter mda = new MySqlDataAdapter(parancs);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("beszallitoi_megrendeles");
        mda.Fill(dt);
        DgUjMegrendeles.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
        mda.Update(dt);
```

and the xaml:

```
<DataGridTextColumn   Width="80" Binding="{Binding MEGRENDEL,StringFormat={}{0:MM/dd}}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
```

Comment: Please post the datagrid definition and  how you fill it using a mysql query